# FileNotFoundException for Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UTFResources when deploying to Azure Websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I'm using Azure Websites git deploy (via Kudu), and everything has been going great, until today. When I do a new git push, and it tries to deploy, I get this error message while my tests are running:

Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UTFResources, Version=10.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I haven't added or removed any libraries or other references from my solution between the last successful push and when I started getting this errors. Googling doesn't turn up anything. That file is in my local GAC, but I can't find it referenced directly anywhere in my solution.

Redeploying an *old* version of my solution - a version that deployed correctly earlier in the day - fails with the same error message.

If I didn't know better, I'd think that MS changed something on their end and broke kudu.

Any thoughts about troubleshooting this, shy of opening a ticket with Azure?

EDIT - More Details:

It's failing while running the unit tests. Here's the relevant portion of my deploy.cmd:

```
:: 1. Build to the temporary path
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  %MSBUILD_PATH% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Payboard.Web\Payboard.Web.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /t:pipelinePreDeployCopyAllFilesToOneFolder /p:_PackageTempDir="%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release /p:SolutionDir="%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\.\\" %SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
) ELSE (
  %MSBUILD_PATH% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Payboard.Web\Payboard.Web.csproj" /nologo /verbosity:m /t:Build /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false;Configuration=Release /p:SolutionDir="%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\.\\" %SCM_BUILD_ARGS%
)

IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 (
    echo Build failed with ErrorLevel !0!
    goto error
)

:: 2. Building test projects
rem echo Building test projects
"%MSBUILD_PATH%" "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\PayboardWeb.sln" /p:Configuration=NoDatabase;VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /verbosity:m /p:Platform="Any CPU"


IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 (
    echo Build failed with ErrorLevel !0!
    goto error
)

:: 3. Running tests
echo Running tests
vstest.console.exe "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Payboard.Common.Tests\bin\NoDatabase\Payboard.Common.Tests.dll"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
vstest.console.exe "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Payboard.Model.Tests\bin\NoDatabase\Payboard.Model.Tests.dll"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
vstest.console.exe "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Payboard.Services.Tests\bin\NoDatabase\Payboard.Services.Tests.dll"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
vstest.console.exe "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Payboard.Integrations.Tests\bin\NoDatabase\Payboard.Integrations.Tests.dll"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
vstest.console.exe "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Payboard.Web.Tests\bin\NoDatabase\Payboard.Web.Tests.dll"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
```

It's failing during the first call to `vstest.console.exe`, after successfully running a whole bunch of the unit tests, but before finishing. Here's an example of the log file:

```
Passed   ConditionalFormatting_ShouldHandleSimpleConditions
Passed   ConditionalFormatting_ShouldHandleComplexNumericConditions
Passed   ConditionalFormatting_ShouldHandleNullStrings
Passed   ConditionalFormatting_ShouldHandleNullObjects
Error: Exception thrown executing tests in D:\home\site\repository\Payboard.Common.Tests\bin\NoDatabase\Payboard.Common.Tests.dll
Passed   ShallowClone_ShouldCopyIntegers
Passed   ShallowClone_ShouldCopyNullableIntegers
Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UTFResources, Version=10.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Passed   ShallowClone_ShouldCopyStrings
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UTFResources, Version=10.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
Passed   ShallowClone_ShouldNotCopyReferences
Passed   ShallowClone_ShouldReturnNullIfSourceIsNull
Server stack trace: 
Passed   ShallowCopyTo_ShouldCopyIntegers
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ExpectedExceptionAttribute..ctor(Type exceptionType, String noExceptionMessage)
Passed   ShallowCopyTo_ShouldCopyNullableIntegers
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ExpectedExceptionAttribute..ctor(Type exceptionType)
Passed   ShallowCopyTo_ShouldCopyStrings
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule pModule, IRuntimeMethodInfo pCtor, Byte** ppBlob, Byte* pEndBlob, Int32* pcNamedArgs)
Passed   ShallowCopyTo_ShouldNotCopyReferences
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject(RuntimeModule module, IRuntimeMethodInfo ctor, IntPtr& blob, IntPtr blobEnd, Int32& namedArgs)
Passed   ShallowCopyTo_ShouldNotCopyExceptions
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
Passed   ShallowCopyTo_ShouldNotCopyExceptionExpressions
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
Passed   GetFriendlyTypeName_ShouldHandleSimpleTypes
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(Boolean inherit)
Passed   GetFriendlyTypeName_ShouldHandleComplexTypes
   at NUnit.Core.Reflect.GetAttributes(ICustomAttributeProvider member, Boolean inherit)
Passed   GetFriendlyTypeName_ShouldHandleReallyComplexTypes
   at NUnit.Core.Reflect.HasAttribute(ICustomAttributeProvider member, String attrName, Boolean inherit)
Passed   MultiDateTimeConverter_ShouldSupportMultipleFormats
   at NUnit.Core.Reflect.HasMethodWithAttribute(Type fixtureType, String attributeName, Boolean inherit)
Passed   OrIfGreater_ShouldSelectGreaterValue
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.NUnitTestFixtureBuilder.CanBuildFrom(Type type)
Passed   OrIfGreater_ShouldSelectRealValue
   at NUnit.Core.Extensibility.SuiteBuilderCollection.CanBuildFrom(Type type)
Passed   OrIfLesser_ShouldSelectGreaterValue
   at NUnit.Core.TestFixtureBuilder.CanBuildFrom(Type type)
Passed   OrIfLesser_ShouldSelectRealValue
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.GetFixtures(Assembly assembly, String ns)
Passed   GetKey_ShouldSupportStrings
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
Passed   GetKey_ShouldSupportInts
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
Passed   GetKey_ShouldSupportDates
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.BuildSingleAssembly(TestPackage package)
Passed   ForEachParallel_ShouldExecuteAllActions
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
Passed   ForEachParallel_ShouldExecuteWithMaxParallelization
   at NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
Passed   SelectParallel_ShouldSelectAllData
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
Passed   SelectParallel_ShouldSelectWithMaxParallelization
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
Passed   SortOfMatches_ShouldMatchSameUrls
   at NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
Passed   SortOfMatches_ShouldIgnoreQueryStrings
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
Passed   SortOfMatches_ShouldIgnoreShortPrefixes
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
Passed   SortOfMatches_ShouldNotMatchOnPathMismatch
Passed   SortOfMatches_ShouldNotMatchOnHostMismatch
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
Passed   MainDomain_ShouldRemoveWww
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
Passed   MainDomain_ShouldRemoveApp
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
Passed   MainDomain_ShouldNotRemoveExample
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
Passed   MainDomain_ShouldNotRemoveMainDomain
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
Passed   MainDomain_ShouldHandleCountryDomains
   at NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.NUnitTestExecutor.RunAssembly(String assemblyName, ITestExecutionRecorder testLog, TestFilter filter, IRunContext runContext)
Total tests: 117. Passed: 116. Failed: 0. Skipped: 1.
Test execution time: 7.5134 Seconds
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Test Run Failed.
```

I should note that if I comment out the calls to the unit tests, I can get it to deploy. So I suppose the question is basically - what can I do to get my unit tests running again? Is it possible that the recent update to the Azure websites - the one that supported, among other things, TypeScript 1.1 - could have possibly removed `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UTFResources.dll` from the GAC? Or something along those lines?

Comment: To troubleshoot, does it also happen if you deploy to a new site? Also, Kudu doesn't run tests by default. Do you have a custom deployment script that does this? Can you give a little more output from the deployment, so show what step this is happening in?

Comment: @DavidEbbo - Thanks for responding. I added some more details.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Were you able to try with a clean site, to make sure that it's not due to something that got in a bad state in that one site? Ideally, if you are able to share a public repo that demonstrates the failure, that would help investigation. The repos that we use that do unit tests are still working with latest, so there must be some difference.

Comment: And to add one thing: that assembly was not in the GAC even before. So it seems the issue is that something tries to load it now while it didn't before.

Comment: @DavidEbbo - I deployed to a new website, and ran into the same problem. Given that the same deploy.cmd with the same .sln file was working earlier, I have to imagine that *something* changed on the server-side. At least, the data seems to point to nothing having changed in the solution itself.

Comment: Agreed, if the same commit ID worked before, it could be some subtle server-side breaking change. If you have a repro that you can share, that would be ideal. It doesn't have to be your full project. If the same can be reproed with something simpler, that's even better.

Comment: @DavidEbbo - Thanks for your help troubleshooting. I've been able to reproduce the deployment error with this somewhat stripped-down Github project (one real library project, one real unit test project, and one empty web application project): https://github.com/smithkl42/Troubleshooting. You should have access - let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks you, this should help a lot! Could you please open an issue on https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu with that repo? This will work better that SO to track the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this does appear to be a recent regression. I have opened https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1370 to track it and discussed further.

Comment: Thanks! I'll track it there.

Comment: I tried the workaround mentioned in the GitHub issue, but when I changed the assembly from 10.1.0.0 to 10.0.0.0, the test explorer doesn't find the unit test.

Answer (score 11):

Have a look here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/35104/systemiofilenotfoundexception-utfresourcesdll.html

The suggestion was to de-reference **Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework** and add NuGet packages **MSTest.TestFramework** and **MSTest.TestAdapter**

On my VSTS build definition, I also had to change the checkout process to clean the **All Build Directories**

This solved the FileNotFound exception I was getting for the same DLL.

Answer (score 0):

I just lower down the version from  10.1.0.0 to 10.0.0.0. and it worked!!!